# Did Douglas Adams say "I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe."?

Tags: quotes, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams

I like the quote:

> I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe.

It seems to sum up some of the weird things and coincidences I encounter in life. The quote is allegedly from Douglas Adams, and it is certainly in his style. However, I cannot find the source of the quote. Sources given include the *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, or *The Restaurant at the End of the Universe* book, and Adams himself. If it is one of the radio shows or books, which one (and which episode/chapter)? Was it added or removed from a certain edition? If directly from Adams, which article, document, newspaper or interview? Or is it a corruption of something else he said or wrote? Was it from one of the records or the film (not heard or seen them)?

The closest I found was in the [section on The Restaurant at the End of the Universe from the Wikipedia article on The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe). It states that pulling tiles from a Scrabble set reveals "What do you get if you multiply six by nine?" and Arthur then comments:

> I've always said there was something fundamentally wrong with the universe.

However, in my battered *The Restaurant at the End of the Universe* book Chapter 32 does not end with the above, but with:

> "I, F," said Ford, "Y, O, U, ... M, U, L, T, I, P, L, Y, ... What do you get if you multiply, ... S, I, X, ... six, B, Y, by, six by ... what do you get if you multiply six by ... N, I, N, E, ... six by nine ..." He paused. "Come on, where's the next one?"
>
> "Er, that's the lot,” said Arthur, “that's all there were."
>
> He sat back, nonplussed.
>
> He rooted around again in the knotted up towel but there were no more letters.
>
> "You mean that's it?" said Ford.
>
> "That's it."
>
> "Six by nine. Forty-two."
>
> “That’s it. That’s all there is.”

If the definitive source cannot be found then the quote will have to be attributed to anonymous. It will mean that the use of the quote in the question [How did Douglas Adams choose the Ultimate Question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12229/how-did-douglas-adams-choose-the-ultimate-question) is incorrect, and in the Wikipedia article linked above and the article [Phrases from The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

Did Douglas Adams say *I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe.*?

Comment: Note the Adams compulsively rewrote his material.  It would not surprise me at all if the dialog in Fit the Sixth was different.

Comment: What a versatile and fitting quote that is. Another gift from Adams.

Comment: Reading the title, I immediately heard Simon Jones' voice in my head. I'd like to urge everyone who had to go looking for a transcript to check this to get hold of a copy of the original radio series on CD/MP3/whatever. It is absolutely fantastic, and the books, while also fantastic, are different in many details.

Comment: @IMSoP - Peter Jones?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica No, [Simon Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Jones_(actor)), who played Auther Dent. Peter Jones was The Book.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As DavidW says in the comments, the dialog in Fit the Sixth of the radio series is slightly different, and does include (very nearly) that quote.

> ARTHUR: That's it. Six by nine. Forty-two. I always said there was something fundamentally wrong with the universe.

(Note, the book of the original scripts includes the sentence "Something's certainly got screwed up somewhere" after "Forty-two", but I'm pretty sure that wasn't actually said in the episode. Most of the lines that were cut are marked with italics in that book, but this one doesn't seem to be.)

Comment: Thanks, I have now found a transcript (https://www.clivebanks.co.uk/THHGTTG/THHGTTGradio6.htm) of the last episode of the first Hitchhikers radio show (12th April 1978) with the line by Arthur "That’s it. Six by nine…forty-two! I always said there was something fundamentally wrong about the universe!". Nice to know it definitively comes from Adams

Comment: @DanielS.Fowler I'm fairly certain that Arthur says the same thing (probably the "I always said..." version) in the TV show as well. That seems to be the case from the script [here](https://subslikescript.com/series/The_Hitchhikers_Guide_to_the_Galaxy-81874/season-1/episode-6-Episode_16). But then this isn't so surprising, as large sections of the TV show scripts are identical to the radio scripts they were based on.

Comment: Also worth noting that these letters come from a Scrabble set, but breaks the rules, since a Scrabble set only has 2 Y's, and this sentence requires 3.  I don't know if this was intentional or falls into the same category as "*I don't write jokes in base-13*" (His actual response when someone told him that 6x9 does indeed equal 42 in base-13.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman If you want a head-canon excuse, remember that this is a _home-made_ Scrabble set, made while stranded in the pre-historic past. It's fairly unlikely that either Ford or Arthur would happen to have the correct letter distributions memorised.

Comment: @IMSoP well *actually*, going back to the point made in the answer, the versions differ and in the radio series it's an actual pocket Scrabble set Arthur had been carrying all along (he mentioned he had it in the Haggunennon ship).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I stand corrected!

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah, there basically is no official canon in the HHG universe.  Between the radio series, the books, the TV series, the video game, and the film (all of which Adams was personally involved in writing even if he didn't survive to see the film), there are so many discrepancies it's impossible to reconcile them.  (And there's apparently a new series coming out next year?  Hmm...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Intriguing... that's the second time today I've seen someone claim that the sentence "what do You get if You multiplY six bY nine" contains three instances of the letter 'y'. Either it clearly has four, or else there's something fundamentally wrong with the Universe. Or mine, at least.

Comment: @Pendantry Right you are - in my mind it was "*six and nine*" not "*six by nine*".  I stand corrected.