# Why did Kubrick reference '42' so often in The Shining?

Tags: the-shining, stanley-kubrick

The website [Snopes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/the-shining-numerological-easter-egg/) documents and posits various reasons behind the number being featured, but finds no conclusive evidence.

Here are the unsupported theories put forward, to save everyone a click:

> A blog created by Kubrick’s fans hypothesized that Kubrick repeatedly referenced the number 42 (as well as 24, 21, and 12) after studying Sigmund Freud‘s writings outlining the “unsettling effect that recurring numbers can have.”
>
> It is possible, as well, the original BBC Radio 4 broadcast of Douglas Adams’ “Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy” — which aired via multiple episodes in 1978 — influenced Kubrick. According to The Frida Cinema, an Orange County art house nonprofit, scenes from “The Shining” were shot in London that same year.
>
> Meanwhile, Geoffrey Cocks, a retired history professor, has a more specific theory. Cocks — a source in the 2012 documentary “Room 237” that dissects the film’s possible hidden messages and author of the book titled, “The Wolf at the Door: Stanley Kubrick, History, and the Holocaust” — believes the “42” reference helps paint an allegory about Nazi extermination.
>
> “1942 was the year of the Final Solution, and 42 has been used as shorthand to refer to the Holocaust,” Vulture published in 2013, citing Cocks’ theory.

Is there an explanation attributable to Stanley Kubrick as to why he referenced the number 42 so often in the movie?

Comment: Maybe Kubrick wass a fan of *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*? It originated as a radio drama in 1978, while *The Shining* movie is from 1980, so the timing makes it just possible.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen and why was `42` referenced there?

Comment: Douglas stated: “The answer to this is very simple. It was a joke. It had to be a number, an ordinary, smallish number, and I chose that one. Binary representations, base 13, Tibetan monks are all complete nonsense. I sat at my desk, stared into the garden and thought ’42 will do.’ I typed it out. End of story.” @Bob

Comment: @JiminyCricket. He didn't have to pick a number. He could've picked `apple pie`. And Lewis Carroll used `42` so it's not the first popular work to use it; it's not chosen randomly.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. For the use of 42 in Hitchhikers’, that’s the answer for people who don’t like answers. [Other, more illuminating answers are available](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/310/why-did-douglas-adams-pick-42-as-the-ultimate-answer)

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen that's already posited in the linked article. I've edited them in to save people the click.

Comment: Are you sure that Stephen King didn't use 42 in the original 1977 novel?

Comment: @Spencer I think King was very keen on the number 19... that's quite prevalent in a lot of his books...

Comment: Because 2 x 3 x 7 = 42

Answer (score -4):

Stanley Kubrick's frequent references to the number '42' in "The Shining" can be interpreted as a multifaceted symbol, intertwining various thematic and philosophical elements that we have discussed. Firstly, the number 42 holds a special place in popular culture due to its mention in Douglas Adams' "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" as the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything. Kubrick, known for embedding deep, often cryptic symbolism in his films, might have used this number to subtly nod towards the search for meaning in the universe, a theme resonant in "The Shining."

Moreover, the number 42's scientific significance, such as its role in the natural formation of rainbows, could symbolize the intertwining of the natural and supernatural elements within the film's narrative. The recurring motif of 42 might be Kubrick's way of hinting at deeper layers of reality, where ordinary aspects of life intersect with profound, often mystical, truths.

In the broader context of our discussion, where we delved into concepts of consciousness as perceived by Spinoza, Jung, and Eastern philosophies, and the interconnectedness of all things as suggested by modern physics and ancient beliefs, the use of '42' in "The Shining" could be seen as a metaphor for the complex layers of reality and perception. It suggests that beneath the surface of the physical world and human psyche lies a more intricate web of connections and meanings.

Kubrick's choice to repeatedly reference '42' could also be interpreted as a reflection on the nature of knowledge and understanding. Just as we discussed the infinite ways in which knowledge systems like physics, biology, and mathematics can be stretched and interpreted, Kubrick's use of '42' might be an artistic expression of this infinite complexity and the elusive nature of truth and understanding.

In summary, Kubrick's use of '42' in "The Shining" can be seen as a rich, multidimensional symbol that resonates with various themes and ideas, from the search for meaning in the universe to the intricate interplay between the natural, supernatural, and human consciousness. It's a testament to Kubrick's mastery in using symbolism to evoke deep thought and contemplation in his audience.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a lot of words, which you probably didn't write, that don't actually provide a strong, evidence-based answer to the question.  Where is the evidence that this is _actually_ why Kubrick used the number?